# iphone TouchJson + ASIHTTPRequest => Android ? +?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, web

Is it

iphone TouchJson + ASIHTTPRequest => Android Gson + DefaultHttpClient

Many thanks

Comment: why is it marked -1? This is very important information for me and really needed to confirm about this before we start development to support multiple devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you're actually storing a DefalutHttpClient into a GSON string make sure you nullify any InputStreams or RandomAccessFiles as GSON will not store these.